# In Grafana How can I turn rows into columns

Tags: grafana

I am trying to turn rows with information into columns in Grafana, but can't figure it out.

I have a table with the following information:

```
-----------------
| Field | Total |
-----------------
| DEBUG | 6     |
| INFO  | 76    |
-----------------
```

That I am trying to change into so I can turn it into a bar graph:

```
----------------
| DEBUG | INFO |
----------------
| 6     | 76   |
----------------
```

Is there any way to make this happen in Grafana?

Comment: What is your Grafana version and how your datasource query looks like?

Comment: @JanGaraj using Grafana v7.5.2 and I have multiple queries (level:"debug") and (level:"info") with a reduce -> Total transformation which reduces it into the table I posted in the question.

Comment: I would try some transformation.

Comment: Did you get a solution. I have the same Problem wanted to get the rows to columns that I can divide it.

Answer (score 5):

I tried "Grouping to matrix", seems to work for my scenario:

I have 3 columns:

```
-------------------------
| Metric | yr   | Value |
-------------------------
| TEMP   | 2000 | 1     |
| PRES   | 2000 | 2    |
| TEMP   | 2001 | 3     |
| PRES   | 2001 | 4    |
-------------------------
```

Using "Grouping to Matrix":

[image: grouping-to-matrix]

I get:

```
-------------------------
| yr\Metric | TEMP   | PRES |
-------------------------
| 2000      | 1      | 2    |
| 2001      | 3      | 4    |
```

Comment: You're godsend.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the type from the default range to an instant did the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under **Transformation** tab use **Rows to fields** transformation.

Comment: The transformation is creating a one-row table.  Is there any way to only move one field's values into multiple fields?

Comment: What do you mean by a one-row table?

Comment: Here I want to convert the "Book" field to have a separate column for each book: https://i.imgur.com/6xwIVl6.png .  But it ends up making columns for all the non-value fields: https://i.imgur.com/daJHVg9.png

Comment: @Jayen, I think you want to convert fieldnames to the first column and value to the second. I'm also looking for that, simply in order to display a vertical table from some metric with a lot of labels

Comment: @oneindelijk I contacted Grafana support and couldn't solve it so ended up with a custom solution.

Comment: ey! Thank you so much! this did the trick for me! <3